# How to exclude a .NET 6 Minimal API from code coverage?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I maintain a class library which contains several reference implementations to demonstrate how the library should be used. I have reference implementations for .Net Framework, core, .NET 5 and now I have added a reference implementation for .NET 6 using minimal APIs.

For all of my other reference implementations I have added the `ExcludeFromCodeCoverage` attribute using `System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis` to all of their containing classes. How would I do something similar for a .NET 6 minimal API?

My `program.cs` looks like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using SharedDataLayer.Repositories;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<PaymentRepository>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/Payments", ([FromServices] PaymentRepository repo) =>
{
    return repo.GetPayments();
});


app.Run();
```

Comment: What code coverage tool are you using?

Comment: JetBrain's dotCover

Comment: The containing class here is `Program`.

Comment: Have you tried the other options here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/Coverage_Results_Filters.html or here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/Runtime_Coverage_Filters.html ?

Comment: It sounds like the problem is top-level statements, not minimal APIs. You're probably trying to disable test coverage for the entire `Program.cs` not just `app.MapGet`

Comment: Why not apply the attribute to the entire assembly? `[assembly: ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I image that `[assembly: ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` would work. However I have discovered that at this time JetBrains isn't providing adequate support for .NET 6 for me to verify this. If you want to add this as an answer, once JetBrains release a version of dotcover that supports .NET6 I'll verify it and mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 6):

Your Program.cs shoud look like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using SharedDataLayer.Repositories;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<PaymentRepository>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/Payments", ([FromServices] PaymentRepository repo) =>
{
    return repo.GetPayments();
});


app.Run();`

[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public partial class Program { }
```

Answer (score -1):

I've tested out the suggestions from the comments on the initial question and can confirm that adding the following to the top of your `program.cs` does work and the file is excluded from code coverage:

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

[assembly: ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
```

Comment: Just to note that this will not only exclude `Program.cs` but the entire assembly.

Comment: This worked for me thanks
[assembly: ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]